# ObservableZip .subscribe() crash: null pointer exception, but what causes it?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I see a lot of these crashes in Google Play Console, but I can't see what exactly in code causes it from the stack trace. How can I find out?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableZip$ZipCoordinator.subscribe (ObservableZip.java:110)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableZip.subscribeActual (ObservableZip.java:72)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:12284)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run (ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
  at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run (Scheduler.java:578)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run (ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call (ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

I checked [RxJava2 ObservableZip.java:110](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/0668d042b47d3585f856af831bd3b1e1742c080f/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/internal/operators/observable/ObservableZip.java#L110) and it's a call to `.subscribe()`. In my code I have `Observable.zip()` in some parts (mostly in Fragments) and it looks like this:

```
DisposableObserver<List<WalletBalance>> walletBalanceUpdateObserver = new DisposableObserver<List<WalletBalance>>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(List<WalletBalance> results) {
        if(isAdded() && getActivity() != null) {
            // process results ...
        }
        this.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() { }
};

Observable.zip(apiCalls, responses -> {
    List<WalletBalance> allWallets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object res : responses) {
        Response<WalletBalance> response = (Response<WalletBalance>) res;
        if (response != null && response.body() != null)
            allWallets.add(response.body());
    }

    return allWallets;
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(walletBalanceUpdateObserver);
```

What could be causing the crash here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

Most likely one of the elements from `apiCalls` in `Observable.zip(apiCalls, responses -> {` is `null`.

### Reproduce

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

class So65600653 {
  @Test
  void zipTest() {
    Observable<Integer> zip =
        Observable.zip(
            Arrays.asList(Observable.just(1), null, Observable.just(3)),
            objects -> {
              return 42;
            });

    Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
        zip.test();
    }).isExactlyInstanceOf(NullPointerException.class);
  }
}
```

### StackTrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableZip$ZipCoordinator.subscribe(ObservableZip.java:110)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableZip.subscribeActual(ObservableZip.java:72)
```

### RxJava Source-Code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (cancelled) {
                return;
            }
            sources[i].subscribe(s[i]); // Line 110
        }
```

In this case, one could say `sources` is null, or `sources[i]` is `null` and calling `subscribe` on `null` will throw a NPE.

But we can rule out, that `sources` is `null` because, it is checked above for it and given to `ZipCoordinator(Observer<? super R> actual, ...`. The `ZipCoordinator` is called from

```
    ZipCoordinator<T, R> zc = new ZipCoordinator<T, R>(observer, zipper, count, delayError);
    zc.subscribe(sources, bufferSize);
```

Which makes sure, that `sources` is not null.

```
    ObservableSource<? extends T>[] sources = this.sources;
    int count = 0;
    if (sources == null) {
        sources = new Observable[8];
        for (ObservableSource<? extends T> p : sourcesIterable) {
```

### Solution

Filter out all `null` values from `apiCalls` before passing to `Observable#zip`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, Hans. I will check and filter out `null`s.

Comment: Your class names are very well organised for reference purposes!  I don't think mine go beyond `Test` :D